# Две третьих рубля или рублей

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Две третьих рубля, так как это расшифровывается как "две третьих части ЧЕГО? рубля"

Answer (score 1):

Можно "расшифровать" и так: две третьих части ЧЕГО? рублей. Число существительного от вопроса не зависит.
 Дробь - это часть от целой **единицы**. Вот поэтому "две третьих рубля" - одного рубля. Хотя треть от единицы вычислить невозможно. Две трети рубля - это 66,6666.... копеек. Вот две трети от двенадцати рублей - это ровно 8 рублей, или две третьих суммы (но не рублей).
Может, математики меня поправят.))

Comment: >Можно "расшифровать" и так: две третьих части ЧЕГО? рублей.  
  
Что-то у меня никак не получается. Виктор неправ только нем, что несколько сократил объяснение. Две третьих чего? - **одного** рубля.
  
Вот треть от единицы - это как раз без проблем.  

Про 2/3 суммы или кучи - это да: *"две третьих [от общего числа] цветов в букете составляли розы"*, но здесь-то совсем иной смысл.

Comment: Нет, @Элен, как математик - поправлю. Две третьих, безусловно, от одного рубля. Разве что Вы рассматриваете "рубли" не как меру стоимости, а как физические бумажки, банкноты. Но тогда так и надо сказать: "Две трети от лежащих на столе 12 рублей были потертыми и тусклыми".

Comment: Да, у меня бестолковое объяснение. Я просто хотела сказать, что правильно "рубля", а объяснение Виктора неверно потому, что на вопрос ЧЕГО? можно дать ответ как "рубля", так и "рублей". А насчёт математики...  Может что-то стоить две третьих рубля.  И вообще,  в каком контексте может быть употреблено это выражение?

Comment: Всем спасибо.

Comment: @Элен, в математической задаче - может стоить. В жизни, при нынешних ценах - вряд ли. Хотя все возможно: если за 3 штуки чего-то просят 2 рубля.

Answer (score 0):

Две  третьих  рублей  можно  сказать  только  в  определённом  контексте,  если  предположить,  что  рядом  с  кучей  рублёвых  банкнот  лежит  куча,  допустим,  тугриков,  столь  любимых  Великим  комбинатором.